# Winform app: Problems with threads and timers

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, timer, threadpool

I am making a very simple program in Winform (C#).

However, I am having some problems with threads and timers. I am receiving a messaged called "The thread '' (0x1e30) has exited with code 0 (0x0)." I have read that this is happens when a thread successfully stops. However, this is not what I want.

The program is called "What Are You Doing Right Now?" and its purpose is to sit in the tray and at random time intervals (say, between 15 and 120 minutes) pop up with a text prompt, asking me to write down what I am doing right now. This is then logged to a simple txt file. The idea is that the mere act having to "confess" about what I am doing will make me more conscious about how I am spending my time in front of the computer (and hopefully become more productive).

[image: Picture of the app]

When I have written some text (e.g."Browsing StackOverflow"), it minimizes to the tray again and starts a new countdown for when to pop up.

The problem is that somehow the main thread stops after some time and thereby makes the timer stop as well. I have no idea why; I did not do anything with threads other than what is made per default when making a WinForm project in Visual Studio 2012.

When logging the output, it looks like this (I appended the comments):

- 5 // app starts counting down
- 4
- 3
- 2
- 1
- 0 // timer is finished, show the window and wait for hitting "Go!" button
- 4 // new countdown
- 3
- 2
- 1
- 0 // does NOT show the window (as intended)?
- 0
- The thread '' (0x6e0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
- 0
- 0 // etc...

My knowledge about timers and threads are not good enough to be able to detect why the thread "No Name" stops at that particular moment.

Here is my code (I have removed some of the less important code; you can see it all here: http://pastebin.com/5Apfgcpy):

```
namespace WhatAreYouDoingRightNow
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
private string _text; // text that the user will write to
private double _timeLeft; // countdown time

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    label2.Visible = true; // debug label to show timer

    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized; // start minimized in tray

    _text = ""; // reset text
    WriteLog(true); // write for the first time of today

    GetRandomTime(); // get new random time interval

    timer1.Interval = 1000; // seconds
    timer1.Start(); // start timer
}

// Go button (either by click or hitting Enter)
private void HitGoButton()
{
    _text = DateTime.Now + " - " + textBox1.Text; // append date and time
    WriteLog(false);

    _text = "";
    GetRandomTime();
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
}

// Open txt file and write to it
private void WriteLog(bool startOfTheDay)
{
    // writes to a txt file using StreamWriter
}

private void GetRandomTime()
{
    Random rand = new Random((int) DateTime.Now.Ticks);

    _timeLeft = rand.Next(1, 2)*5; // multiplied by 60 to get    minutes instead of seconds
}


// Count down to random time and then display the box
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // count down
    if (_timeLeft > 0)
        _timeLeft--;

    label2.Text = _timeLeft.ToString(); // debug label to show time
    notifyIcon1.Text = _timeLeft.ToString(); // debug show time in tray
    Console.WriteLine(_timeLeft); // debug write time to console window

    // if time ran out --> show the window
    if (_timeLeft <= 0)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
}



private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        HitGoButton();
}

private void Form1_Resize_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        this.Hide(); // only show in tray icon, not in task bar
    }
    else if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
    {
        this.Show();
    }
}
  }
}
```

Can anybody see why my program only works one time and then exits the thread and stops counting?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 1:** Here is the designer file as well: http://pastebin.com/yvWs2VVp

**UPDATE 2:** Here is the code for Program.cs (I haven't changed anything):

```
namespace WhatAreYouDoingRightNow
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the designer file as well? (on pastebin)

Comment: There's nothing clearly wrong with this code and no obvious reason why the timer's Tick event won't run.  The debugger notification isn't that useful, the .NET framework is thread-happy in general.  If it was the UI thread then the NotifyIcon wouldn't work anymore either.  What's missing is the code that creates an instance of this form and calls Application.Run(), it could matter if it is not the boilerplate code in Program.cs

Comment: I have added both my designer file and Program.cs in the opening post (see update 1 and 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. Apparently I was overriding some functionality in the Form's Resize event that made the program unable to work.

If I comment out the following, the program works as intended:

```
private void Form1_Resize_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                this.Hide(); // only show in tray icon, not in task bar
            }
            else if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
            {
                this.Show();
            }*/
        }
```

Comment: The only minor problem is that even though I set it NOT to display on the task bar, when it minimizes, it is shown in the left bottom corner behind where the Windows start button is. My taskbar automatically hides, so I can see the app's title bar when I am toggling between programs.

Comment: I just solved this by setting the Opacity to either 100 or 0, depending on whether I want it to be displayed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you stop the timer while the form is showing to the user? Then re-enable the countdown while it is hidden.

Comment: That was my first thought as well. I did that, using timer1.Stop() and timer1.Start(), but the result was the same. I thought I was somehow stopping the timer code to run again, so I decided to make it tick all the time but only subtract from my _timeLeft variable when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong but it seems to me that you wish to have your window pop up at random times between 15 minutes and 120 minutes? Im going to break this up into steps.

**Step One**

If that is the case then your `GetRandomTime` method should look like this:

```
private void GetRandomTime()
    {
        Random rand = new Random(); /*You do not need to supply it the current
 datetime as the random class uses a time dependent default seed value */

//look at the constructor http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx 

        _timeleft = rand.Next(15, 120) * 60 * 1000; /*here you are telling the random 
"I want any number between 15 and 120 but in order to get this to vibe with the timer's
 interval format you need to multiply by 60 first for the seconds and 1000 to convert
 to milliseconds. */

    }
```

So basically from the above random if you end up with say 24.. you multiply that by 60 to get 1440 and then by 1000 to get 1440000 which is how many milliseconds there are in 24 minutes. What you had before would always get you a 5. Now on to step two..

**Step Two**

Now you need to alter your tick handler

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // count down
        if (_timeLeft > 0)
            _timeLeft = _timeleft - 1000; //Since your interval is 1s subtract that.

        label2.Text = ((_timeLeft / 1000) / 60).ToString() + " minutes left"; // convert back to minutes
        notifyIcon1.Text = ((_timeLeft / 1000) / 60).ToString() + " minutes left"; 
        Console.WriteLine(((_timeLeft / 1000) / 60).ToString() + " minutes left"); 

        // if time ran out --> show the window
        if (_timeLeft <= 0)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
    }
```

For quicker debugging purposes I suggest you change your random method to give you a hardcoded 1. Then see if your program closes and opens again every 1 minute.

```
//Debugging version of GetRanomdTime
    private void GetRandomTime()
    {
        //Random rand = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

        _timeleft = 1 * 60 * 1000;
    }
```

Comment: I see your point, but I believe that the following line (in Form1's constructor) does convert it into seconds automatically:

"timer1.Interval = 1000; // seconds"

I just tried putting in your code instead, but the result is still the same with the thread exiting out.